# Trying to create tables from JSON with multiple "table" blocks

Tags: javascript, json

Good afternoon. What I am trying to accomplish is to create tables using the JSON that has been sent to me. If the JSON file contains a single block for a table, it all works fine. Multiple tables are an issue though. Below is an example of the JSON with data for two tables and the JS that I have so far to build the table into the HTML that I have also included. Any insight will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
[
{
    "table": {
        "tableDetails": [
            {
                "filecreatedate": "8/28/2014 10:43:08 AM",
                "Name": "Personal Loans",
                "PrintUrl": "print friendly url here",
                "EffectiveDate": "3/7/2014",
                "disclosure": "disclosure "
            }
        ],
        "headers": [
            {
                "Header1": "Personal Loans",
                "Header2": "Loan Amount",
                "Header3": "Fee",
                "Header4": "APR",
                "Header5": "Calculator"
            }
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
                "PersonalLoans": "VISA Platinum Rewards",
                "LoanAmount": "$1000 - $25,000",
                "Fee": "$0.00",
                "APR": "9.15%",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "PersonalLoans": "VISA Platinum Low Rate",
                "LoanAmount": "$500 - $25,000",
                "Fee": "$0.00",
                "APR": "8.15%",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "PersonalLoans": "Cash-in-a-Flash",
                "LoanAmount": "$500 [1]",
                "Fee": "$30.00",
                "APR": "17.90%",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "PersonalLoans": "Lifestyle Loan",
                "LoanAmount": "$500 - $5000",
                "Fee": "$0.00",
                "APR": "10.99%",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "table": {
        "tableDetails": [
            {
                "filecreatedate": "8/28/2014 10:43:34 AM",
                "Name": "Fixed Rate Second Mortgage",
                "PrintUrl": "print friendly url here",
                "EffectiveDate": "5/1/2014",
                "disclosure": "disclosure text"
            }
        ],
        "headers": [
            {
                "Header1": "Loan Amount",
                "Header2": "APR LTV <=80%",
                "Header3": "APR LTV 80.01-90%",
                "Header4": "Note",
                "Header5": "Calculator"
            }
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
                "Loan Amount": "$50,000+",
                "APR LTV <=80%": "5.950%",
                "APR LTV 80.01-90%": "6.700%",
                "Note": "10 Yr",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "Loan Amount": "$49,999-25,000",
                "APR LTV <=80%": "6.200%",
                "APR LTV 80.01-90%": "6.950%",
                "Note": "10 Yr",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "Loan Amount": "$24,999-5,000",
                "APR LTV <=80%": "6.450%",
                "APR LTV 80.01-90%": "7.200%",
                "Note": "10 Yr",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "Loan Amount": "$50,000+",
                "APR LTV <=80%": "6.200%",
                "APR LTV 80.01-90%": "6.950%",
                "Note": "15 Yr",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "Loan Amount": "$49,999-25,000",
                "APR LTV <=80%": "6.450%",
                "APR LTV 80.01-90%": "6.950%",
                "Note": "15 Yr",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "Loan Amount": "$24,999-5,000",
                "APR LTV <=80%": "6.700%",
                "APR LTV 80.01-90%": "7.450%",
                "Note": "15 Yr",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "Loan Amount": "$50,000+",
                "APR LTV <=80%": "6.500%",
                "APR LTV 80.01-90%": "7.250%",
                "Note": "20 Yr",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "Loan Amount": "$49,999-25,000",
                "APR LTV <=80%": "6.750%",
                "APR LTV 80.01-90%": "7.500%",
                "Note": "20 Yr",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            },
            {
                "Loan Amount": "$24,999-5,000",
                "APR LTV <=80%": "7.000%",
                "APR LTV 80.01-90%": "7.750%",
                "Note": "20 Yr",
                "Calculator": "<a href='#'><img src='img/calc.gif' alt='Calculator' /></a>"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

]

And the JS:

```
$("table#tbl").wrap("<div class='rate_table' />");
$("table#tbl").append("<tbody></tbody>");
var a = {};
$.getJSON("path/taken/out/for/SO", function(b) {
a = b;
$.each(a, function(e, c) {
    for (var f = 0; f < c.table.tableDetails.length; f++) {
        $("table#tbl").before(c.table.tableDetails[f].Name);
    }
});
$.each(a, function(e, c) {
    for (var f = 0; f < c.table.headers.length; f++) {
        $("table#tbl thead").append('<th class="col_0">' + c.table.headers[f].Header1 + '</th><th class="col_1">' + c.table.headers[f].Header2 + '</th><th class="col_2">' + c.table.headers[f].Header3 + '</th><th class="col_3">' + c.table.headers[f].Header4 + '</th><th class="col_4">' + c.table.headers[f].Header5 + "</th>");
    }
});
$.each(a, function(e, c) {
    for (var f = 0; f < c.table.columns.length; f++) {
        $("table#tbl tbody").append("<tr><td>" + c.table.columns[f].PersonalLoans + "</td><td>" + c.table.columns[f].LoanAmount + "</td><td>" + c.table.columns[f].Fee + "</td><td>" + c.table.columns[f].APR + "</td><td>" + c.table.columns[f].Calculator + "</td></tr>");
    }
});
$.each(a, function(e, c) {
    for (var f = 0; f < c.table.tableDetails.length; f++) {
        $("p.rateDisclosure").append(c.table.tableDetails[f].disclosure);
    }
});
});
```

All of this is to build a table with the following html

```
<table id="tbl">
<thead></thead>
</table>
<p class="rateDisclosure">&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: You must built it dynamically, which means each `'table'` you must create new table, from your html, will only build once.

Comment: I should clarify. Yes, I would like to be able to select which table in the JSON file I am going to use. I have tried using [0] or [1] to identify the table element I am using. No such luck. Syntactically I am missing something.

Comment: I added a solution for this that loops through the tables array, and renders each one dynamically, please see below..

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Thanks. Works pretty well. Getting some undefined stuff, but I can work that all out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the JSON data in a loop and add tables dynamically instead of relying on static elements (inject the `table` element instead of putting it in the html).

(If you don't care about the other tables, just grab the first index and pass it through your rendering routine instead of looping.)

Here is an example fiddle that dynamically renders multiple tables using your JSON example response: http://jsfiddle.net/6wdksrkp/2/

**And the code solution for you:**

```
$.getJSON("path/taken/out/for/SO", function(tables) {
    // this is the ajax callback code, goes inside your ajax function
    if (tables) {
        for (var i = 0, len = tables.length; i < len; i++) {
            RenderTable(tables[i]);
        }
    }
}

function RenderTable(tableDef) {
    // create table element template dynamically as a fragment before adding to DOM
    var $tbl = $("<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>");

    // wrap the table in a div (for styling and identification)
    $tbl.wrap("<div class='rate_table' />");

    // render the table name before the table element
    var a = tableDef;
    $.each(a, function (e, c) {
        for (var f = 0; f < c.tableDetails.length; f++) {
            $tbl.before(c.tableDetails[f].Name);
        }
    });

    // render column headers in THEAD
    $.each(a, function (e, c) {
        for (var f = 0; f < c.headers.length; f++) {
            $tbl.children("thead").append('<th class="col_0">' + c.headers[f].Header1 + '</th><th class="col_1">' + c.headers[f].Header2 + '</th><th class="col_2">' + c.headers[f].Header3 + '</th><th class="col_3">' + c.headers[f].Header4 + '</th><th class="col_4">' + c.headers[f].Header5 + "</th>");
        }
    });

    // render the columns' data in TBODY
    $.each(a, function (e, c) {
        for (var f = 0; f < c.columns.length; f++) {
            $tbl.children("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + c.columns[f].PersonalLoans + "</td><td>" + c.columns[f].LoanAmount + "</td><td>" + c.columns[f].Fee + "</td><td>" + c.columns[f].APR + "</td><td>" + c.columns[f].Calculator + "</td></tr>");
        }
    });

    // update rate disclosure
    $.each(a, function (e, c) {
        for (var f = 0; f < c.tableDetails.length; f++) {
            $("p.rateDisclosure").append(c.tableDetails[f].disclosure);
        }
    });

    // inject the table fragment into the DOM (thus showing the table)
    $(document.body).append($tbl);
}
```

Comment: I haven't used this site before, I would like this to be upvoted. Great solution.